# Can I check if Map contains key or not in Visual Force page under the <apex:repeat> tag

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapOfID [Lpartner]}" var="InvestorDistributor" rendered="{!mapOfID[Lpartner] == true}"> 
    <table width="100%">     
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="30%" align="left">
            {!InvestorDistributor.Name}"
            </td>
            <td width="10%" align="center">
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'-'dd'-'yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!InvestorDistributor.navpeII__Distribution_Date__c}"/> 
            </apex:outputText>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" align="Right">{!InvestorDistributor.navpeII__Total_Distributions__c }"</td>
            <td width="12%"></td>
            <td width="18%"></td>
            <td width="10%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
    <apex:variable value="{!totaldistribution+ InvestorDistributor.navpeII__Total_Distributions__c }" var="totalContribution" />
    </apex:outputPanel>                  
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: It appears this is a duplicate of the above mentioned question. If the answers given there do not give you an answer, please do consider that you haven't really explained your question or provided any details. Generally, it's better to explain things a bit more, so we have more to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done! You can use a [wrapper class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15752/320), or marshall them into an arbitrary in-memory SObject (eg `WebLink`) in your controller, which won't whinge about null values when accessed in Visualforce.