# How to check is the map key exist or not

Tags: visualforce, rendered, outputpanel

Hi on my VF page I want to render output panal on the based of if the key exist or not. I wan to check if the key exist or not. While checking I am getting an error that

> Map key result__c not found in map

My code to check the key and render the output panel

```
   <apex:repeat value="{!visitFieldNames}" var="vfld">
      <apex:variable var="vfldDesc" value="{!visitFieldDescMap[vfld]}" />
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(visitRecord[vfld] != null, true, false)}">
                 <option value="{!visitRecord[vfld]}" selected="selected">{!visitRecord[vfld]}</option>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Why I am getting error I also tried by using

```
    rendered="{!if(visitRecord != null, true, false)}"
```

But still I am getting the same error. Please guide me how can I achieve it.

Comment: In the past it wasn't possible to check - see [can we check if a key exists in a map in vf page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15748/can-we-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-map-in-vf-page). So unless this has changed in the last year or so you will have to do the work in the controller.

Comment: The "containsKey()" method in the controller is the only way I could think! Alternatively you can try with the following: "You can build a delimited string with all the keys of the map in controller and then you use SF formula

CONTAINS(delimited_string_with_map_keys, key)" as mentioned in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15748/can-we-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-map-in-vf-page.