# Map key - not found in map

Tags: apex

I am pretty new to Apex , so it would be great if anyone can help me debug the error .

This is my map getting initialised

```
public Map < String,RecordSum.TotalBlock > TotalBlock {set;get;}
```

Later in the code

```
TotalBlock = new Map < String,RecordSum.TotalBlock >();
```

Error message :

> Map key - not found in map Error is in expression '{!IF(data.account.Flag__c <>null , TotalBlock[data.account.Type__c+'-'+data.account.Flag__c+'-'+data.account.Line__c].‌​Total,TotalBlock[data.account.Type__c+'-'+data.account. Line__c].Total )}' in component  in page ABCD

How do I approach such an error?

Comment: Please paste your full code in here.

Comment: and also paste the error message please

Comment: Error message : Map key - not found in map
Error is in expression '{!IF(data.account.Flag__c <>null , TotalBlock[data.account.Type__c+'-'+data.account.Flag__c+'-'+data.account.Line__c].Total,TotalBlock[data.account.Type__c+'-'+data.account. Line__c].Total )}' in component <apex:outputText> in page ABCD

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming that your VF throws error as Map Key is not found.

The solution is to check the key in Apex Code, and prevent the rendering of the element or component before the attempted access.

Its a fairly common issue with people have already taken shot at it :

[can we check if a key exists in a map in vf page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15748/can-we-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-map-in-vf-page)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed VisualForce throws an error when a key is not found in the map, so you have to take care of knowing wether the key is there or not.